# HTML text field value passed to a php file is null

Tags: php, html

I have an html code that passes the values of text fields to a php file. To check for the value of these variables , I use echo to print the values but nothing gets printed.

This is my html code:

```
 <form action="connect.php" type="post">
   Username: <input type="text" name = "uname"><br>
   Confirm Username: <input type="text" name = "cuname"><br>
   Password: <input type="password" name = "pword"><br>
   Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="cpword"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Sign up">
 </div>
 </form>
```

This is my connect.php code:

```
<?php
  $info1 = isset($_POST['uname']);
  $info2 = isset($_POST['cuname']);
  $info3 = isset($_POST['pword']);
  $info4 = isset($_POST['cpword']);

  echo $info1;
  echo $info2;
  echo $info3;
  echo $info4;
?>
```

Comment: `isset` returns `true` or `false`. What do you expect that code to do?

Comment: @deceze The OP's problem is that *nothing* gets printed at all.

Answer (score 1):

a) correct:

> ```
> <form action="connect.php" type="post"> 
> to   <form action="connect.php" method="post">
> ```

b) mostly, you don't "pass the values of text fields to a php file", you
   are trying to output the input at screen. If you want to save and
   reuse them, you have to use a database.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="connect.php" method="POST">
   Username: <input type="text" name = "uname"><br>
   Confirm Username: <input type="text" name = "cuname"><br>
   Password: <input type="password" name = "pword"><br>
   Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="cpword"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Sign up">
 </div>
 </form>
```

the php....

```
  <?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) //if form submitted...
    {
  $info1 = $_POST['uname']; // Get POST value
  $info2 = $_POST['cuname'];
  $info3 = $_POST['pword'];
  $info4 = $_POST['cpword'];

  echo $info1;
  echo $info2;
  echo $info3;
  echo $info4;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`isset()` is a boolean function that tells you if a variable is set or not. If you want to print the value itself, try:

```
$info1 = $_POST['uname'];
echo $info1;
```

If you want to see what comes from the function, try debugging with:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Answer (score -1):

To avoid errors like `Undefined index` you can always use [the at sign (@)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

```
<?php
  $info1 = @$_POST['uname'];
  $info2 = @$_POST['cuname'];
  $info3 = @$_POST['pword'];
  $info4 = @$_POST['cpword'];

  echo $info1;
  echo $info2;
  echo $info3;
  echo $info4;
?>
```